# Deadlock When Streaming From subprocess.Popen And Using Two Subcommands

Tags: python, python-3.x, streaming, subprocess, wsgi

In my wsgi application, I have to call a commandline tool to generate data and sometimes another commandline tool to convert that data. It all works through stdout/stdin. I'm using subprocess and I formerly used communicate, which worked fine but was slower since it's not streaming and trying to convert it to stream incrementally from the stdout is what's causing me problems.

Old code (works but isn't streaming):

```
generator_process = subprocess.Popen(generator_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if convert_command:
    convert_process = subprocess.Popen(convert_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

output, err = generator_process.communicate()

if convert_command:
    output, err = convert_process.communicate(output)

yield output
```

Current code - works fine for me when it doesn't need to do conversion. But gets stuck on subprocess.stdout.read() otherwise (using readline instead doesn't make a difference one way or another):

```
generator_process = subprocess.Popen(generator_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, bufsize=1)
convert_process = None
if convert_command:
    convert_process = subprocess.Popen(convert_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)

while True:
    chunk = generator_process.stdout.read(chunk_size)
    if convert_process:
        if chunk:
            convert_process.stdin.write(chunk)
        chunk = convert_process.stdout.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk: yield chunk
        else: break

    else:
        if chunk: yield chunk
        else: break
```

Note that since this is a wsgi application so asyncio/coroutines won't work (something I realized after going down the asyncio rabbit hole).

Is there any way with python as it stands right now to stream from a subprocess to the client without possibility of deadlock?

Comment: Have you tried changing the buffer size to a larger value (something like 4096) or to unbuffered (0)?  I could see a deadlock happening if the write buffer hasn't flushed before being read in and vice-versa.

Comment: I did play with the buffer sizes to no avail. Even reading the whole thing at once didn't do it. My mistake was just not setting the output file-like object to be the input on the convert process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the child processes tries to read from stdin then the only reason for the deadlock that I see in your code is that `.write(chunk)`, `.read(chunk_size)` may go out of sync if `convert_process` does not return byte for byte (if `.flush()` after `.write(chunk)` does not help).

To emulate `generator | convert` command in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from functools import partial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

def get_chunks(generator_command, convert_command, chunk_size=1024):
    with Popen(generator_command, stdin=DEVNULL,
               stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL) as generator_process, \
         Popen(convert_command, stdin=generator_process.stdout, 
               stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL) as convert_process:
        yield from iter(partial(convert_process.stdout.read, chunk_size), b'')
    return generator_process.returncode, convert_process.returncode
```

Comment: Adding flush didn't help, but setting stdin=generator_process.stdout did. I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: @pinkboi: unrelated: I've preserved `yield` interface here but I would normally just call `shutil.copyfileobj(convert_process.stdout, output_stream)` instead. Or even set `stdout=socket_obj` on `*nix` systems (like `nc` or `socat`).